# ubuntu update error and cannot install latest version of nodejs

Tags: ubuntu-18.04, apt-get

when I update my ubuntu, I got some long line of error and warning message and also some of ppa cannot be updated like nodejs.

```
youngjinkim@vm-youngjinkim:~$ sudo apt-get update          
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                                                                                       
Hit:3 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                                                                               
Hit:4 http://kr.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease                                                                             
Ign:5 http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable InRelease                                                                                       
Get:6 http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable Release [8604 B]                                                                                     
Get:7 http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable Release.gpg [819 B]                                                                                           
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                                     
Hit:9 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                                                                      
Hit:10 https://packages.microsoft.com/repos/vscode stable InRelease                                                             
Hit:11 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ansible/ansible/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Ign:7 http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable Release.gpg
Ign:13 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:14 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/icons/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Hit:15 http://ppa.launchpad.net/noobslab/themes/ubuntu bionic InRelease
Err:16 http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu bionic Release
  404  Not Found [IP: 172.30.252.31 8080]
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable Release: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY B1998361219BD9C9
E: The repository 'http://repos.azulsystems.com/ubuntu stable Release' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/docky-core/stable/ubuntu bionic Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: Target Packages (main/binary-amd64/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Packages (main/binary-all/Packages) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target Translations (main/i18n/Translation-en) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11 (main/dep11/Components-all.yml) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons-small (main/dep11/icons-48x48.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target DEP-11-icons (main/dep11/icons-64x64.tar) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-amd64) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
W: Target CNF (main/cnf/Commands-all) is configured multiple times in /etc/apt/sources.list:58 and /etc/apt/sources.list.d/vscode.list:3
```

I wanna update nodejs cache policy, but when I do update, I got this message and then I checked nodsjs ppa version is 8, so I cannot install latest version of nodejs.

and I recognize W: warining , E: error but what is N??

Answer (score 0):

I solve the problem by

- step 1: install vim

  ```
  $ sudo apt-get install vim
  ```
- step 2: enter the source list on your error, eg:

  ```
  $ sudo vim /etc/apt/sources.list
  ```
- step 3: comment the line on the error, and the problem will be solved.